# In Azure DevOps, is it possible to add a Test Plan with all Test Suites to a build pipeline (YAML) automatically?

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, yaml, azure-pipelines, test-plan

I use Azure DevOps Test Plans and Test Suites to execute automated tests in a YAML build pipeline.
For each release I create a new Test Plan with new Test Suites.
Actual I search manually for IDs of Test Plan and Test Suites and copy them to the YAML file.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run automated UI tests'
  inputs:
   testSelector: testPlan
   testPlan: 585
   testSuite: 586,929,930,680,683,684,685,931,681,686,687,688,767,682,689,690,691,768,692
   testConfiguration: 2
   uiTests: true
   testRunTitle: 'Automated UI testing'
```

Is there a possibility to do that automatically?
Or a possibility to reduce the manual effort e.g. just change the Test Plan ID in Pipeline and all Test Suites are automatically included?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the below answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: No sorry, I tried to change the YAML file by a CmdLine@2 task before. But it seems that when the pipeline was started, changes in the YAML file doesn’t have any effect.

Comment: @mkr How about using rest api in a powershell task? You can view my answer to see if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility to do that automatically? Or a possibility to
> reduce the manual effort e.g. just change the Test Plan ID in Pipeline
> and all Test Suites are automatically included?

You can get the test suites for the test plan through the script in a Powershell task, and then assign the obtained result to a variable.

Use Test Suites - [Get Test Suites For Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20suites%20for%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/suites?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Sample script:

```
$url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/suites?api-version=6.0-preview.1';

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get

$testSuites = $response

Write-Host "results = $($testSuites | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

In VSTest task:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run automated UI tests'
  inputs:
   testSelector: testPlan
   testPlan: 585
   testSuite: $(testSuites)
   testConfiguration: 2
   uiTests: true
   testRunTitle: 'Automated UI testing'
```

Answer (score 0):

The YAML file is in your repository. So you can edit this file through REST API. Here is an example: [Update a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-file). In this case, you may have some template of your YAML file, identify Test Plan ID and Test Suites ([Get a test suites for plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20suites%20for%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-a-test-suites-for-plan.)), then update
the YAML file with new IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full solution that works as of 3/1/2022 using [Azure DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-suites/get-test-suites-for-plan?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    $organization = "YOUR ORG NAME HERE"
    $project = "YOUR PROJECT NAME HERE"
    $planId = 585
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN -AsPlainText -Force

    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/Plans/$planId/suites?api-version=5.0"
    $cred = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList "AzPipeline", $password

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Authentication Basic -Method Get -Credential $cred

    $testSuites = $response |
      ForEach-Object{ $_.value.id} |
      Join-String -Separator ', '

    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testSuites;]$testSuites"
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: testPlan
    testPlan: 585
    testSuite: $(testSuites)
    testConfiguration: 2
    uiTests: true
    testRunTitle: 'Automated UI testing'
```